# Using Time To Live(TTL) for spring data cassandra repository

Tags: spring, spring-data, cloud-foundry, spring-data-cassandra

Not able use TTL with spring data CassandraRepository based implementation.

Spring data cassandra version: Latest

I am trying to use TTL property of cassandra for save operation using spring data repository based implementation. however looking at the reference documentation(https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/) i dont see any straight forward way of using it.

Even though docs mentioned that we can use it but no example provided for repository based implementation. Do note that i see some example using cqlTemplate and cassadraOperations. But none for repository.

```
No code written yet as I am trying to figure out how to use it
```

Expectation would be some kind @TTL(value in seconds) annotation on repository save/update method for easier implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to A Sarkar's answer from this post [TTL support in spring boot application using spring-data-cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34505376/ttl-support-in-spring-boot-application-using-spring-data-cassandra)

Please see my sample code here, https://github.com/nontster/spring-data-cassandra-demo

I borrow sample code from this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-tutorial

You need to create demo keyspace before you can run this code,

```
CREATE KEYSPACE demo WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};
```

Run saveBookTest() method in BookRepositoryIntegrationTest.java and you can see countdown TTL in column via (I set TTL to 600 seconds)

```
cqlsh:demo> SELECT title,TTL(year) FROM Book WHERE title='Head First Java' AND publisher='O''Reilly Media';

 title           | ttl(year)
-----------------+-----------
 Head First Java |       597
```

(1 rows)